# Graphite Integration breaks ganglia/gmetad?

Tags: monitoring, ganglia, graphite

I'm trying to forward metrics from gmetad to graphite/carbon. After configuring `carbon_server` and `ganglia_prefix` in `gmetad.conf` gmetad starts losing metrics.

gmetad Version is 3.3.5, carbon/whisper/graphite-web is 0.9.8.

There is no I/O bottleneck on the system and no CPU bottleneck (HP DL385G7 with 2 SSDs in RAID0), I even configured another gmetad on a remote host to send metrics to graphite/carbon, which also broke down.

Does anyone else experience this?

Comment: Please show us the details configuration? Can you telnet to `gmetad` port?

Comment: gmetad runs perfectly, as soon as I add `carbon_server` and `ganglia_prefix` some threads in gmetad start segfaulting and rrds are not updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got that fixed with two small bash & perl scripts (dirty hack ahead)

g2g.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use XML::Simple; 


$now = time;
$ref = XMLin("-");
$clustername = $ref->{"CLUSTER"}{"NAME"};
foreach (@{$ref->{"CLUSTER"}{"HOST"}}) {
    $hostname = $_->{"NAME"};
    $hostname =~ s/\./_/g;
    $hostname = "here.goes.my.prefix.".$clustername.".".$hostname; 
    foreach (@{$_->{"METRIC"}}) {
        print "$hostname".".".$_->{"NAME"}." ".$_->{"VAL"}." ".$now."\n";
    }
}
```

ganglia2graphite.sh

```
#!/bin/sh 

while true ; do 
    nc localhost 8649 | /usr/local/bin/g2g.pl | nc -q1  localhost 2003
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but the above perl script isn't working for me (fails with an error "Not an ARRAY reference at g2g.pl").

However, I think I found a fix.  Just ensure carbon_server is an IP address without quotes.  That seems to work just fine for me:

```
carbon_server a.b.c.d
carbon_port 2003
graphite_prefix "ganglia"
write_rrds off
```